# pptp server change location of chap-secrets file

Tags: vpn

Dont ask me why I need to use pptp when there's openvpn and dont ask me why but I need to change the location of the chap-secrets file to a custom place. Symbolic links are also out of the question.

If there is a way of changing this file's location from the default one (/etc/ppp/) please share it.

Answer (score 2):

By default chap-secret file location is /etc/ppp/chap-secrets however you can specify other location by adding the following code in accel-pptp.conf:

```
[chap-secrets]
chap-secrets= path to chap-secrets location
```